# How to integrate Apple Pay for Enterprise App which is distributed through MS AppCenter?

Tags: ios, enterprise, applepay, appcenter

We have two apps running in parallel.
A customer application in the official app store which is running fine with Apple Pay.
A copy of the customer application which we distribute through an Enterprise profile via MS AppCenter to employees. You can understand this copy-app as some kind of "beta" application.
We chose AppCenter, because this way users don't need to download Testflight as separate or "external" application first.

When introducing new tested features, we first deliver those first to our employees.
If all is fine, the feature will be deployed for customers as well.

Currently we can find no way to integrate Apple Pay in our Enterprise build.
Seems like Apple does not allow to enable this functionality somehow. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Why not using TestFlight? Your beta tester could test Apple Pay without having to actually pay. Wouldn’t it be what you are willing to do ?

Comment: Pick one: ApplePay or Enterprise distribution